# Trying to remove my own stopwords using join/split

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove stopwords in df['Sentences'] as I would need to plot it. 
My sample is

```
...        13
London     12
holiday    11
photo      7
.          7
           ..
walk       1
dogs       1
```

I have built my own dictionary and I would like to use it to remove the stop_words from that list. 
What I have done is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


    df['Sentences'] = df['Sentences'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([item for item in x.split() if item not in my_dict]))
    w_freq=df.Sentences.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()
```

Although it does not give me any error, the stopwords and punctuation are still there. Also, I would like to not alterate the column, but just looking at the results for a short analysis (for example, creating a copy of the original column).

How could I remove them?

Comment: is `my_dict` a dictionary or the list because I'm not sure that doing `item not in my_dict` would work if you don't get the list of stopwords you defined?

Comment: Hi @Ben.T. `my_dict` is a list. `my_dict=['a', 'an', 'the', 'of', 'on',...]`

Comment: I have also tried with `.apply(lambda x: [item for item in str.split(x) if item not in my_dict]) `but I got the following output: `Series([], dtype: int64)`

Comment: I'm a bit confuse by your question, the sample data you give is the one before you do the apply or you try to apply on column?

Comment: it is the output that I got applying the code on the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have this dataframe with this really interesting conversation.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sentences':['Hello, how are you?', 
                                'Hello, I am fine. Have you watched the news', 
                                'Not really the news ...']})
print (df)
                                     Sentences
0                          Hello, how are you?
1  Hello, I am fine. Have you watched the news
2                      Not really the news ...
```

Now you want to remove the punctuation and the stopwords from `my_dict`, you can do it like this

```
my_dict = ['a','i','the','you', 'am', 'are', 'have']
s = (df['Sentences'].str.lower() #to prevent any case problem
                    .str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', '') # remove the punctuation
                    .str.split(' ') # create a list of words
                    .explode() # create a row per word of the lists
                    .value_counts() # get occurrences
    )
s = s[~s.index.isin(my_dict)] #remove the the stopwords
print (s) #you can see you don't have punctuation nor stopwords
news       2
hello      2
watched    1
fine       1
not        1
really     1
how        1
           1
Name: Sentences, dtype: int64
```

This might not be the faster way though

Comment: Thank you so much @Ben T. It is not removing the white spaces. How could I remove them?

Comment: @still_learning hmm indeed I just see it in my ouput. You can add a whitespace in the stopwords maybe? because you do it after all the process, it won't affect the result of the split for example

Comment: `locs=['...','–','``','“','\'\'','«','»','·']` I cannot see the whitespace here. This is the only part in my_dict where I consider punctuation

Comment: @still_learning wait I'm not sure to understand what you mean then. where it is not removing the whitespaces?